# Why we need to explicitly initialize the final variable of a class?

Tags: java

if an instance variable of a class has a default initial value then why we need to explicitly initialize the `final` instance variable of class?
 I mean to say if we are not initializing the final variable it should take default value because that is the property of instance variable of a class.

Comment: Final it self mean that.

Comment: I mean to say if we are not initializing the final variable it should take default value because that is the property of instance variable.

Comment: What point is there in a `null`-valued final variable? You can just replace all its occurences with `null`.

Comment: yes in object case there is no point in using that but in case of primitive data type at least it can come in use for some cases.